# Filter tweets by matching criteria in R

Tags: r, twitter

I am completely new to R programming.
trying to learn on my own.
I have a scenario like,i have bunch of tweets.
and i would like to filter those tweets by based on word, if it exits in that tweets text, then it should get all the tweets and also its other attributes.

**sample.json**

```
{"created_at":"Wed Oct 12 06:33:06 +0000 2016","id":786092312011112448,"id_str":"786092312011112448","text":"I posted a new photo to Google https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":359430735,"id_str":"359430735","name":"Life Changing Quotes","screen_name":"dadhwalashish","location":"Jalandhar India","url":"http:\/\/www.CompassionKindness.com","description":"@armyofkind , Human Resources professional, Blogger, Happiness ambassador, Kindness warrior, Love agent, Humanity over all religion.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1919,"friends_count":1973,"listed_count":41,"favourites_count":24456,"statuses_count":20738,"created_at":"Sun Aug 21 15:39:19 +0000 2011","utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/359430735\/1472921460","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","display_url":"fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","indices":[33,56]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1476253986729"}
{"created_at":"Wed Oct 12 06:33:06 +0000 2016","id":786092312011112448,"id_str":"786092312011112448","text":"I posted a new photo to Google https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":359430735,"id_str":"359430735","name":"Life Changing Quotes","screen_name":"dadhwalashish","location":"Jalandhar India","url":"http:\/\/www.CompassionKindness.com","description":"@armyofkind , Human Resources professional, Blogger, Happiness ambassador, Kindness warrior, Love agent, Humanity over all religion.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1919,"friends_count":1973,"listed_count":41,"favourites_count":24456,"statuses_count":20738,"created_at":"Sun Aug 21 15:39:19 +0000 2011","utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/359430735\/1472921460","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","display_url":"fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","indices":[33,56]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1476253986729"}{"created_at":"Wed Oct 12 06:33:06 +0000 2016","id":786092312011112448,"id_str":"786092312011112448","text":"I posted a new photo to Facebook https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":359430735,"id_str":"359430735","name":"Life Changing Quotes","screen_name":"dadhwalashish","location":"Jalandhar India","url":"http:\/\/www.CompassionKindness.com","description":"@armyofkind , Human Resources professional, Blogger, Happiness ambassador, Kindness warrior, Love agent, Humanity over all religion.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1919,"friends_count":1973,"listed_count":41,"favourites_count":24456,"statuses_count":20738,"created_at":"Sun Aug 21 15:39:19 +0000 2011","utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/359430735\/1472921460","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","display_url":"fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","indices":[33,56]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1476253986729"}
{"created_at":"Wed Oct 12 06:33:06 +0000 2016","id":786092312011112448,"id_str":"786092312011112448","text":"I posted a new photo to Google https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":359430735,"id_str":"359430735","name":"Life Changing Quotes","screen_name":"dadhwalashish","location":"Jalandhar India","url":"http:\/\/www.CompassionKindness.com","description":"@armyofkind , Human Resources professional, Blogger, Happiness ambassador, Kindness warrior, Love agent, Humanity over all religion.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1919,"friends_count":1973,"listed_count":41,"favourites_count":24456,"statuses_count":20738,"created_at":"Sun Aug 21 15:39:19 +0000 2011","utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/359430735\/1472921460","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","display_url":"fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","indices":[33,56]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1476253986729"}{"created_at":"Wed Oct 12 06:33:06 +0000 2016","id":786092312011112448,"id_str":"786092312011112448","text":"I posted a new photo to Google https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":359430735,"id_str":"359430735","name":"Life Changing Quotes","screen_name":"dadhwalashish","location":"Jalandhar India","url":"http:\/\/www.CompassionKindness.com","description":"@armyofkind , Human Resources professional, Blogger, Happiness ambassador, Kindness warrior, Love agent, Humanity over all religion.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1919,"friends_count":1973,"listed_count":41,"favourites_count":24456,"statuses_count":20738,"created_at":"Sun Aug 21 15:39:19 +0000 2011","utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/359430735\/1472921460","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","display_url":"fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","indices":[33,56]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1476253986729"}
{"created_at":"Wed Oct 12 06:33:06 +0000 2016","id":786092312011112448,"id_str":"786092312011112448","text":"I posted a new photo to Twiiter https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":359430735,"id_str":"359430735","name":"Life Changing Quotes","screen_name":"dadhwalashish","location":"Jalandhar India","url":"http:\/\/www.CompassionKindness.com","description":"@armyofkind , Human Resources professional, Blogger, Happiness ambassador, Kindness warrior, Love agent, Humanity over all religion.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1919,"friends_count":1973,"listed_count":41,"favourites_count":24456,"statuses_count":20738,"created_at":"Sun Aug 21 15:39:19 +0000 2011","utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/759986435453837312\/26b_K_9u_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/359430735\/1472921460","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/5SBpo628DF","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","display_url":"fb.me\/1nqsSEAnu","indices":[33,56]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1476253986729"}
```

**Words.txt**

```
google
facebook
twitter
```

If google word is exists in tweets:text then it should get all the tweets which that word contains,and same as for rest of the words.
I am trying it on my own but need some experts adivce.
What is the best way to do it.Please suggest me any references and books or documents tos follow.

Thanks in advance.
Mohan.V

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You could start off with something like this:

```
# words to match
words <- c("google","facebook","twitter")
# sample words. put real jsons here
sample.jsons <- c("google","twitch","twitter","twitch","facebook","twitch","google","facebook","twitter")
# run through all jsons and target words
for(i in seq_along(sample.jsons)){
  for(j in seq_along(words)){
    # if this condition is TRUE, your criteria is fullfilled
    if(words[[j]] %in% sample.jsons[[i]]){
      # do whatever you want with the jsons which match your criteria
      # right now the following command just outputs all index values at which the criteria is fulfilled
      print(i)
    }
  }
}
```

However, I strongly suggest that you (a) take a look at the SO guidelines and rules and (b) at the very basics of R programming before continuing. Cause if you don't you are pretty likely to have the next problem right away.

Good places to start are:

- [The Art of R Programming](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/132/NSPpart.pdf) by Norman Matloff
- [Google's R Styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml)
- [Learn R](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFAYD0dt5xCzTQHDhMPZwBoaAXWeVhZzg) YouTube tutorials

Comment: @Bunny if this answer helped, please consider selecting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark. This lets community know the answer worked and the issue is closed.